# changing each item in list of tuple to its integer value

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

how can I change the following:

```
from itertools import product
list1 = input().split()
list2 = input().split()
result = product(list1, list2)

for item in result:
    print(item, end=" ")
```

to print:

```
1 2
3 4
(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)
```

instead of:

```
1 2
3 4
('1', '3') ('1', '4') ('2', '3') ('2', '4')
```

?

UPDATE: even though I have written the following code it still has the same problem:

```
from itertools import product
list1 = input().split()
list1_cleaned = []
for item in list1:
    if int(item)>0 and int(item)<30:
        list1_cleaned.append(int(item))
list2 = input().split()
list2_cleaned = []
for item in list2:
    if int(item)>0 and int(item)<30:
        list2_cleaned.append(int(item))
result = product(list1, list2)

for item in result:
    print(item, end=" ")
```

and prints:

```
1 2
3 4
('1', '3') ('1', '4') ('2', '3') ('2', '4') 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Why are you using `if int(item)>0 and int(item)<30:`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/itertools-product

Comment: Ah ok, you just need to map to int as suggested in the answers, also you can simplify your if to  `if  0 < item < 30:`

Comment: where in @pythonista code should I add this?

Comment: `filtered_int =  lambda lst: filter(lambda x: 0 < x < 30,  map(int, lst))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way. You could just use the map separately, I just wanted to use a lambda.

```
  >>> from itertools import product
  >>> list1 = input().split()
  1 2
  >>> list2 = input().split()
  3 4
  >>> to_int = lambda x: map(int, x)
  #or, result = product(map(int, list1), map(int, list2)) whichever you prefer.
  >>> result = product(to_int(list1), to_int(list2))
  >>> for item in result:
  ...     print(item, end=" ")
  ...
  (1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4) >>>
```

Types:

```
  >>> result =  product(to_int(list1), to_int(list2))
  >>> for item in result:
  ...    for val in item:
  ...        print(type(val))
  ...
  <class 'int'>
  #so on and so forth
```

Edit: In your update you convert to an `int` and check if the integer is in (0, 30), but when you use `product` you still have a list of strings.

Comment: can the constraint checking go to filter as well or where should it be?

Comment: something like this ` filter(lambda x: x>0 and x<30, num)`

Comment: That'll work. Although as noted in the other comment section you can shorten that expression.

Answer (score 2):

Use `list(map(int, input().split()))` to transform your input strings into lists of integers. When you form the product of your lists, you'll get tuples of integers instead of tuples of numeric strings.